# Did Gene Roddenberry actually hate that the test orbiter was named Enterprise?

Tags: star-trek

I've been told several times when discussing ships named Enterprise that Roddenberry hated the test orbiter being named Enterprise. This can't be true, can it?

Comment: Yes, it can be true. No idea whether it is or not, but it can be.

Comment: According to his wife he was very appreciative - "***JP:** I'm sure that he felt very proud and honored with the ground swell of public opinion that resulted in NASA agreeing to name the first Shuttle the "Enterprise." **MBR:** *And extremely shocked. And very, very surprised and very appreciative. What an honor.* - http://www.astrodigital.org/space/intmajel.html

Answer (score 12):

As pointed out by @Valorum in the original comments:

While not directly from Roddenberry, this was presented in an interview with Majel Barret Roddenberry ([interview at this link](http://www.astrodigital.org/space/intmajel.html)):

> JP: I also understand that Gene was quite a supporter of the space program.
>
> MBR: Oh my yes.

Followed a question later by:

> JP: I'm sure that he felt very proud and honored with the ground swell of public opinion that resulted in NASA agreeing to name the first Shuttle the "Enterprise."
>
> MBR: And extremely shocked. And very, very surprised and very appreciative. What an honor.

And as shown in the below photo and [in the photo on space.com](https://www.space.com/21856-shuttle-enterprise-with-star-trek-cast.html), he went to the unveiling (Roddenberry is to the right, between Nimoy and Koenig).

[image]

Comment: But do we have anything from Gene himself?

Comment: God, all those leisure suits...